# What happens to Fiora's ultimate versus invisible champion

Tags: league-of-legends

Say, Fiora uses her ultimate on Twitch and the person on their team with oracle get's out of Twitch's range, making Twitch invisible again, will Fiora's ultimate keep hitting him?

Comment: I smell... SCIENCE!?! :D

Answer (score 6):

If Fiora targets a champion with her ultimate and that target becomes invisible/out of sight then the ultimate ends. You can see an example of this with Akali's shroud below: